# Prove $\langle k \rangle / \langle km \rangle \simeq \mathbb {Z}_m,$ where $\langle k \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $k$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Given $k,m \geq 0$, prove $\langle k \rangle / \langle km \rangle \simeq \mathbb {Z}_m$ where $\langle k \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $k$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

I think this is an immediate consequence of the fact that

> Every finite cyclic group of order n is isomorphic to the additive group of $Z/nZ$, the integers modulo n.

Because $\langle k \rangle / \langle km \rangle $ has order $m$. I still want to give a more explicit proof, defining an isomorphism.

The set $\langle k \rangle / \langle km \rangle $ could be descriibed as $\{[k], [2k], \dots [mk]\}$. Then if we define $\phi:\langle k \rangle / \langle km \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ by $\phi([xk]) = [x]$ the function $\phi$ is bijective, thus the sets are isomorphic.

Comment: What is $\left<k\right>$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The group generated by $k$.

Comment: Presumably, that actually means the **subgroup** of some group $G$ generated by $k\in G$. So what is $G$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I edited my question. $G$ is Z.

Comment: As $\Bbb Z$ is an additive group, then why are you considering $[k^2]$ etc.?

Comment: Your last paragraph is not correct, if by $\langle k\rangle/\langle km\rangle$ you mean some group with additive law of combination.

Comment: @Lubin I changed the description of the group. Is it right now?

Comment: Yes, right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the efficient way to do this is to consider a group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to k\Bbb Z/km\Bbb Z$, which can also be written, as you do, as $\langle k\rangle/\langle km\rangle$.

The homomorphism I have in mind is $n\mapsto[kn]$, where the latter is the coset of $kn$ in $k\Bbb Z/km\Bbb Z$. This homomorphism is clearly onto, and what’s the kernel? Multiples of $m$, i.e. the group $m\Bbb Z$. Thus, by the First Isomorphism Theorem, $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\cong k\Bbb Z/km\Bbb Z$